# Problem using in GWT project classes from other project/source folders

Tags: gwt, class, external

My project contains 2 source folder, one is generic J2EE application another is smartCleintGWT,

I want to use some already existing DTO classes from first source folder (src)

Note that class used on client side and on server side of GWT project!

When I do that I getting error

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/..Projects/Admin/DMX/src_console/com/ho/nod/client/AdminRPC.java'
[ERROR] Line 7: No source code is available for type com.dmx.synch.server.descriptors.DMXLicense; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Source is available obviously; is there any way to import all that into GWT?

PS In the future 2 source folder will be separated into 2 projects...I hope it wont be that complicated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find in the [good docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules):

> Modules can specify which subpackages
>   contain translatable source, causing
>   the named package and its subpackages
>   to be added to the source path. Only
>   files found on the source path are
>   candidates to be translated into
>   JavaScript, making it possible to mix
>   client-side and server-side code
>   together in the same classpath without
>   conflict. When module inherit other
>   modules, their source paths are
>   combined so that each module will have
>   access to the translatable source it
>   requires.

To add another subpackage add `<source path="package"/>` in your host file (`*.gwt.xml`). From the log you posted, it seems you have to add source from the `com.dmx.synch.server` package.

Answer (score 0):

Most RPC problems are related to Serializablity of the DTO in question, can you need to ensure that the classes have default constructor and also check if the Module definition file i.e. .gwt.xml file has source element pointing to these packages.

Answer (score 0):

GWT only looks for source code in the client package by default, so if you have added new packages you must specify this in your *.gwt.xml file.
Add something like: source path='your_top_dir' in XML format.